# static library that dependency on another static libray (Linux) undefined

Tags: linux

I would like to combine (include) a static library to another.
When I try that on Windows, it works.
On linux, the object is not included in the newly created library. Looking inside the created library you find the function name but as undefined with ' U '.
What kind of flags needs to force the object to be included in the newly created library?

```
nm -g libPPCL.a  | grep  "pathLib"

U _Z12CheckpathLibRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
0000000000000000 T _Z15CallpathLibFuncRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

the function is CallpathLibFunc , and the library has the name pathLib which should be inside PPCL.a

joining third party library to my own library

Note:

I use premake5 to generate the makefile and VS2022 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Check out my template project that describes the solution.

https://github.com/MariwanJ/TemplatePremakeStaticLIB
The idea is to extract the .o files and add them to the .lib again. This must be done inside the lua file for the head library (you want to bring vendor library to it).
Please check the solution and test it if you want.

Here how you should do for the linux:

```
--- Combine join two libraries into one library
filter "system:linux"
    postbuildcommands {
    "ar -x " ..  (linuxOutput .. "/bin/libpathLib.a"),
    "ar -x " ..  (linuxOutput .. "/bin/libPPCL.a"),
    "ar -r " ..  (linuxOutput .. "/bin/libPPCL.a") .." "  ..  ("*.o"),
    "rm -f *.o"  -- Remove temporary object files
}
```